# SQL Server 2008: should I create full text index on 'short phrase' column

Tags: sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I have around 100 000 records and a column which contains 2-3 words phrases. I would like to search on this column using `like` functionality or similarly. The question is: should I build a full text index on this column?
Another question: would building a simple non-clustered index on this column improve `like`'s speed?
And finally: how much space would such full-text index take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I build a full text index on this column?

For 100,000 rows I am not sure that you will benefit that much from it. You are properly in the area where it would be more conclusive to test it.

> would building a simple non-clustered index on this column improve like's speed?

`LIKE 'foo%'`? Yes. `LIKE '%foo%'`? No. Think of a phone book, which is indexed by "Lastname, Firstname". Very easy to find all the Smiths, not very easy to find all the Johns.

> how much space would such full-text index take?

Far too speculative. You're going to have a hard time getting an authoritative answer to this. Again I suggest you need to test.